# google sheets get range by having the first cell address and the length

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of 2*n numeric data points and I want to extract a subset of values. Just Like the below schema of my data, the **"Start Of the Range:"** and **"Length Of the Range:"** are inputs and the **"Desired Range:"** is what have to be generated.

[image]

Is that possibe in google sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({B2:2;COLUMN(B2:2)}),CONCATENATE("select Col1 where Col2",IF(B5<0,"<=",">="),CELL("col",INDIRECT(B4&"1")),IF(B5<0," order by Col1 desc",)," limit "&ABS(B5)),0)))
```

Comment: can you help me with this question too?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601081/google-sheets-reverse-the-values-in-a-row-not-sorting-it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @idfurw for his correct answer. I also found that I can use `OFFSET()` function. The benefit that `OFFSET` Provides over `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` is that it also works for negative offsets:

 if **"Length Of the Range"** is positive:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(B4&"2"),0,0,1,B5)
```

if **"Length Of the Range**" is negative:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(B4&"2"),0,B5+1,1,ABS(B5))
```

and this is the final(little complex) version that works for both cases:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(B4&"2"),0,IF(B5>=0,0,B5+1),1,ABS(B5))
```

Comment: You are correct. I have forgot that `OFFSET` support outputting a range. But when it is negative, you want the output to be in asc or desc order?

Comment: @idfurw great point. I think the default order is ASC. any suggestion for making it DESC?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDIRECT(B4&"2:"&ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(INDIRECT(B4&1))+B5-1))
```

[image]