# google sheets reverse the values in a row( Not sorting it)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

this the simplified version of my input and output:

[image]

I want to do it by functions not by extra rows or columns.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any blank cell between the data

If presence, blank cell would be excluded

For example, `A,B,C,,E` outputs `E,C,B,A` (blank cell eliminated)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({B14:14;COLUMN(B14:14)}),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc",0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A), {ROW(A1:A), A1:E}, 
 ABS(SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(A:E))-COLUMNS(A:E)-2), 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Very handy answer. It also supports blank cells. is there any simpler version for just one row of data? if there is, I would appreciate if you post that too(plz dont delete your current answer) and have the both versions.

Comment: @Salar for single row you van do: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1), {ROW(A1), A1:E1}, 
 ABS(SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(A:E))-COLUMNS(A:E)-2), 0)))`